# std::make_pair (no matching function for make_pair)

Tags: c++, std-pair

```
std::pair<std::vector<Gtk::TargetEntry>, int> MyClass::get_drag_info()
{
    return std::make_pair<std::vector<Gtk::TargetEntry>, int>(
                   m_drag_targets, m_drag_data_format);
}
```

Why the above function does not work?
and how do I make it work?

Comment: `make_pair` is intended to *deduce* the pair template arguments. If you want to provide those explicitly, just use `pair<..>(..)` or in C++11, brace-initialization `return {..}`.

Comment: What are the types of `m_drag_targets, m_drag_data_format`? And what is the complete error message?

Comment: Please provide more information about the context. If possible, please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @interjay m_drag_target and m_drag_data_format are of type as typed in return type of a function, answer by doctorlove solved the problem

Comment: @dyp thanks for putting this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You frequently get this message when you haven't included the required header.

For `std::make_pair` you must `#include <utility>`

As noted in the comments you don't need to specify the template arguments...

```
return std::make_pair(m_drag_targets, m_drag_data_format);
```

should suffice.

Comment: lol yes, I don't know for what reason did I include template arguments.

Comment: you got typo here, "inlucde"